# Loop through json and return only true elements

Tags: python, json, api

Via API, I receive json output and instead of writing all the output for analysis, I only want data with a "true" value.

**Sample of raw json data:**

```
scans:
   Scanner1:
      detected: false
      version: "1.1.1.1"
      result: null
      update: "14123412"
   Scanner2:
      detected: true
      version: "2.2.2.2"
      result: "trojan"
      update: "23142551"
```

**Python code**

```
with open('C:\\output.json', 'w') as outfile:
   for item in data["scans"]:
      if 'item["detected"] === true
         json.dump(data)
```

**Desired Output**

```
scans:
    Scanner2:
       detected: true
       version: "2.2.2.2"
       result: "trojan"
       update: "23142551"
```

This by no means works and I don't know JSON, but I had to show I tried lol.

Thank you!

**Update**

```
import requests


url = '<url>'
params = {'apikey': <key>, 'resource': '<value>'}
response = requests.get(url, params=params)

result = []
with open('C:\\output.json', 'w') as outfile:
  data = response.json()
  for i in data['scans']:
    if (i['detected']=='true'):         // error thrown here
      result.append(i)                  // TypeError: string indices must be integers


print(result)
```

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON...

Comment: Is that a yaml file?

Comment: No.. it is a JSON object

Comment: JSON usually has { } and [ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your raw data json does not look like json (look up what json looks like). But assuming that it is copied wrong, the following dictionary comprehension will work for json:

---

```py
data = response.json()

with open('C:\\output.json', 'w') as outfile:
    result = {k: v for k, v in data['scans'].items() if v['detected']}
    outfile.write(json.dumps(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result =[]
with open('C:\\output.json', 'w') as outfile:
  data = json.load(outfile)
  for i in data['scans']:
    if i['detected']=='true':
      result.append(i) 

print(result)
```

Comment: thanks! I now get the error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers` via the line `if (i['detected']=='true'):`. I believe it's looking for an index, requiring something like [0] but I don't quite understand the `i`'s placement. Refer to edits above for everything! please and thank you for the help!